# Custom Workflow creates multiple tasks items when item created triggers workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am brand new to sharepoint and suffice to say the journey has been somewhat problematic so far due to discovering a number of bugs with the software, such as crashes on importing a visio diagram into the SPD2013, i have also had issues around the suspended state, problems aside i have a further issue which i feel can be resolved as i believe it relates to my workflow design in some way.

I have been learning workflow design via the Pluralsight tutorials as i have a large workflow to implement for my Employer.  I need to create a workflow which allocates tasks to various departments and employees as part of a new employee process.  So this is how i tackled the problem:

I created a list which contains all my columns and custom content types with custom outcomes where required.  I then created quite a large workflow with parallell blocks so many tasks are allocated out to various employees to trigger their responsibilities at the start of the workflow.  I have my workflow to trigger when a new item is created on my new employee list.

The problem:  When a new item is added to the list (which triggers the workflow) i get multiple items added below the newly created task.  I am thinking this is due to having a custom content type for each column.  For eg.  Custom content type: Order Hardware with a custom outcome of Ordered/Not Ordered along with a further column for choices and it records these as new items, when they should simply just be tasks as part of the item.

I was thinking around, creating a new custom content type (Employee, and then add all the custom columns into this single content type) is this possibly where i have gone wrong?

**Summary:**  I need to create a large workflow with multiple tasks, which updates a list so progress can be tracked and tasks completed before a particular start date.

Any advice would be warmly appreciated.

## Edit

Many thanks for taking the time to reply.

I have since deleted my workflow and removed the custom content types, in case i was getting a sub-site sharing problem of sharing CCT's across sub-sites.  I intend to recreate them all under the target sub-site where the workflow will function.

Regarding what is missing, i simply had the following there for each stage/step

Log an action
Assign an action
If statement
Update list
Log an action

I am about to recreate the workflow again this evening, and if i have the same error i will repost a fresh image so it provides more visibility of the actions etc.

[image: Image of stripped out workflow]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your parallel processing tasks? When you are doing a bunch of things at the same time, chances are a couple of those are what are generating your dup tasks.

Comment: @Joshmcclain question revised!